# Access iif function seems to change the way criteria in a where clause are interpreted

Tags: ms-access, iif

I'm automating a number of reports in Access 2007 based on events that occurred on the previous business day.  On Tuesday through Saturday the previous business day is the day before.  On Mondays the previous business day is two days before. One of the reports concerns petty cash payments that are timestamped.  It's simple to get the previous workday's records using the Date() function and a Between statement:

```
WHERE Paid_Out_Datetime Between Date()-1 AND Date()
```

This returns a list of payments from the previous day to the present (which will be around 4am of the current day).  But if you put it in an iif function as:

```
WHERE Paid_Out_Datetime =  iif(Weekday(Date())=2,Paid_Out_Datetime Between Date()-2 AND Date(), Paid_Out_Datetime Between Date()-1 AND Date())
```

...no Records are returned.  If you just use `Paid_Out_Datetime = Date()-1` you won't get any records unless a payout happened to have been made at exactly the same time on the previous day.  Putting the Between criterion inside an iif function seems to cause it to behave differently than it does as a single criterion.  My where clause seems pretty straightforward; any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: "This returns a list of payments from the previous day to the present" are you sure? I do not think the present will be included.

Comment: According to some documentation that I saw today the Between statement is inclusive, which is not what I remembered from several years ago--the last time I had work involving Access.  But you are right.  I just ran a test and today was not included.  But I really only want yesterdays records anyway--part of the reason for the reports running in the early am.  But this isn't the issue that concerns me.  I'm wondering why when you put "Between Date()-1 And Date()" in an iif function as one of the arguments no records are returned.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is not what I am seeing. I am getting records returned.